# awk function to modify several columns with regex in a csv

Tags: regex, bash, macos, csv, awk

Goal:

I need to modify urls to leave only the number in it (latitude/longitude/id):
In a .csv-File i have one "certain Titel in Header". This one i need to find. In the column of this found Titel, i will need to delete the beginning and the end of the urls, so its only left a number what was part of the url. This i will need to do on different structured csv with several columns with different Titels and different url-patterns. Is there a way to write a function in bash with awk?

I tried - and its not working because its missing a lot of missing knowledge:

```
#!/bin/bash
CSVFILE=$(find ./aufzubereiten -type f ! -name ".DS_Store") #only one file in this folder.
FILENAME=$(basename "$CSVFILE")

function modify_col() {
    COL= how to find the right column in the csv?
    awk -F',' OFS="," -v pat='"$PAT"' '{sub(/pat/,X,$${COL})} 1' "$CSVFILE" > "$CSVFILE".tmp1 && mv "$CSVFILE".tmp1 "$CSVFILE"
}

COLTITEL="certain Titel in Header"
PAT='/Text1234Text[0-9]{5,8}Text1.html'
PATNEW=''
modify_col

COLTITEL="certain Titel2 in Header"
PAT='/Text2234Text[0-9]{5,8}Text2.html'
PATNEW=''
modify_col

COLTITEL="certain Titel3 in Header"
PAT='/Text3234Text[0-9]{5,8}Text3.html'
PATNEW=''
modify_col
```

Examplefile:

```
header1, header2, certain Titel in Header, certain Titel2 in Header, certain Titel3 in Header
,,/Text2234Text7846641Text.html,/Text2234Text8974341Text2.html,/Text2234Text823241Text3.html
,,/Text2234Text7846642Text.html,/Text2234Text8974342Text2.html,/Text2234Text823242Text3.html
,,/Text2234Text7846643Text.html,/Text2234Text8974343Text2.html,/Text2234Text823243Text3.html
```

Result should be:

```
header1, header2, certain Titel in Header, certain Titel2 in Header, certain Titel3 in Header
,,7846641,8974341,823241
,,7846642,8974342,823242
,,7846643,8974343,823243
```

Thank you for your Ideas :)

Comment: does the data really consist of 3x occurrences of the literal `Text` in the file name?  If 'yes', there are a few (relatively) easy solutions (see below); if the **real** file names are made up of different textual strings then we'll need to see some of the real file names and more details on how said names are to be parsed

Comment: @markp You are right. I was not clear. Thank you a lot for your Efforts and Ideas. After reading and understanding the answers a bit, i realized that I just should have mentioned that in different row is the identical Text who shouldn't be touched. Thats why i tried to "find" the right column.

Comment: yes, without solid examples (input and output) we leave a lot to interpretation, which is (one reason) why [How to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) was created :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
}
FNR==1{
  print
  next
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    sub(/^\/Text[0-9]+Text/,"",$i)
    sub(/Text.*/,"",$i)
  }
}
1
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding a detailed level of explanation of above code.

```
awk '
BEGIN{                                 ##Starting BEGIN section of code here.
  FS=OFS=","                           ##Setting FS and OFS to comma here.
}
FNR==1{                                ##Checking condition if FNR==1 then do following.
  print                                ##Printing the current line here.
  next                                 ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){                  ##Starting a for loop to traverse into all fields here.
    sub(/^\/Text[0-9]+Text/,"",$i)     ##Substituting from starting Text digits Text with NULL in current field.
    sub(/Text.*/,"",$i)                ##Substituting everything from Text to till last of field value with NULL in current field.
  }
}
1                                      ##1 will print edited/non-edited line here.
'  Input_file                          ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 2):

Assumption:

- data looks **exactly** like the sample in the question, ie, the literal `Text` shows up in 3x locations within each `html` file name

Sample data:

```
$ cat text.dat
header1, header2, certain Titel in Header, certain Titel2 in Header, certain Titel3 in Header
,,/Text2234Text7846641Text.html,/Text2234Text8974341Text2.html,/Text2234Text823241Text3.html
,,/Text2234Text7846642Text.html,/Text2234Text8974342Text2.html,/Text2234Text823242Text3.html
,,/Text2234Text7846643Text.html,/Text2234Text8974343Text2.html,/Text2234Text823243Text3.html
```

One `awk` solution:

```
$ awk -F"Text" '
BEGIN  { OFS="," }
FNR==1 { print ; next }
       { print ",,"$3,$6,$9 }
' text.dat
```

Where:

- `-F"Text"` - use `Text` as our input field separator
- `OFS=","` - set output field separator
- `FNR==1 {print ; next}` - for row #1 (header row) print the entire row and skip to next row in the file
- `print ",,"$3,$6,$9` - print 2 commas and then fields 3, 6 and 9 (separated by `OFS=","`)

Result:

```
header1, header2, certain Titel in Header, certain Titel2 in Header, certain Titel3 in Header
,,7846641,8974341,823241
,,7846642,8974342,823242
,,7846643,8974343,823243
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a generalized solution to look for numbers with five or more digits, and delete everything else.

```sh
awk -F , 'BEGIN { OFS=FS }
  FNR>1{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) {
        gsub(/(^|[^0-9])[0-9]{1,4}([^0-9]|$)/, "", $i);
        gsub(/[^0-9]+/, "", $i);
    }
  } 1' filename
```

If you only have a single filename, there is probably no reason to use `find`. If you don't know the name of the file but there is only one file in the current directory, `*` will expand to that file name.

This is slightly brittle in that it will not do the right thing if two numbers within a field are separated by a single non-number character. It's not hard to fix this but I'm lazy and your requirements are slightly vague.

Answer (score 0):

I know OP asked if there is a way to make it using awk, but from the context provided I understand that any solution that would run in a bash script would solve OP's problem.

For such case, I believe `sed` is a more elegant solution:

```
sed 's/[^,]\+[^0-9]\([0-9][0-9]\+\)[^,]\+/\1/g' data.csv
```

It outputs any number with 2 or more digits which is closer to the end of the field. The extended version of `sed` may help to visualize it better:

```
sed -E 's/[^,]+[^0-9]([0-9][0-9]+)[^,]+/\1/g' data.csv
```

output:

```
rvb@ubuntu:~$ sed -E 's/[^,]+[^0-9]([0-9][0-9]+)[^,]+/\1/g' data.csv
header1, header2, certain Titel in Header, certain Titel2 in Header, certain Titel3 in Header
,,7846641,8974341,823241
,,7846642,8974342,823242
,,7846643,8974343,823243
```